# how to show significant and insignificant coeficients in a corrplot when use insig equall 'blank"?

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

I'm using this code:

```
corrplot(v_cor, 
     method="color", 
     col = c('#bf9000ff','#f1c232ff','#ffe599ff','#fff2ccff','#c9daf8ff','#a4c2f4ff','#3c78d8ff','#21437aff'),  
     type="lower", order="original", 
     addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
     tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, #Text label color and rotation
     # Combine with significance
     p.mat = p_val, sig.level = 0.1, insig = "blank",
     # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
     diag=FALSE )
```

I have this result:
[1st result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx8eS.png)

But I want to show the insignificant coefficients but the box must be blank.
e.g.

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKMl6.png)

UPDATE:
I was able to solve this problem and added one more line.

```
    corrplot(v_cor, 
     method="color", 
     col = c('#bf9000ff','#f1c232ff','#ffe599ff','#fff2ccff','#c9daf8ff','#a4c2f4ff','#3c78d8ff','#21437aff'),  
     type="lower", order="original", 
     addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
     tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, #Text label color and rotation
     # Combine with significance
     p.mat = p_val, sig.level = 0.1, insig = "blank",
     # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
     diag=FALSE ) -> p1                                      
      text(p1$x, p1$y,round(p1$corr, 2) ,cex= 0.8, font = 2)
```

Comment: Why not use an example from one of the help files? As it stands there may be minimal input because we do not have `v_cor` to work with.

Comment: @IRTFM I've been using `library(corrplot); v_cor <- cor(mtcars, method = "spearman"); p_val <- 0.5 - v_cor` to get started looking at potential solutions, but I haven't been able to come up with anything - there may not be a 'simple' solution to this problem...

Comment: [Edit] your question body to include that coed (no, not any coeds... the code). DO NOT use comments for substantive mods or improvements to questions.

Comment: I updated the code and I was able to solve that problem.